# reducing the If else condtion code in javascript

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code to fetch the data present and store it in Array format but I thing I have wrote code multiple times can It be possible to minimize the code as its too long

```js
let topicsValue = ["requiredType.*", "Entry.*", "token.*", "RestAPI.*"];

let Topic = [],
  rest = ["required", "unrequired"],
  final = ["createInput", "mustPossible", "finalOutput"];
topicsValue.map((data) => {
  let requiredType, entries, token, restAPI;
  if (data.split(".")[1].includes("*")) {
    if (data.split(".")[0].includes("requiredType")) {
      for (const value of final) {
        requiredType = data
          .split(".")[0]
          .replace("requiredType", "required_type")
          .concat(`.${value}`);
        Topic.push(requiredType);
      }
    }
    if (data.split(".")[0].includes("Entry")) {
      for (const value of final) {
        entries = data
          .split(".")[0]
          .replace("Entry", "entries")
          .concat(`.${value}`);
        Topic.push(entries);
      }
      for (const value of rest) {
        entries = data
          .split(".")[0]
          .replace("Entry", "entries")
          .concat(`.${value}`);
        Topic.push(entries);
      }
    }
    if (data.split(".")[0].includes("token")) {
      for (const value of final) {
        token = data
          .split(".")[0]
          .replace("token", "tokens")
          .concat(`.${value}`);
        Topic.push(token);
      }
      for (const value of rest) {
        token = data
          .split(".")[0]
          .replace("token", "tokens")
          .concat(`.${value}`);
        Topic.push(token);
      }
    }
    if (
      data.split(".")[0].includes("RestAPI") &&
      !data.split(".")[0].includes("RestAPIAction")
    ) {
      restAPI = data
        .split(".")[0]
        .replace("RestAPI", "restAPI")
        .concat(`.deploy`);
      Topic.push(restAPI);
    }
  } else {
    if (data.split(".")[0].includes("requiredType")) {
      if (!rest.includes(data.split(".")[1])) {
        requiredType = data
          .split(".")[0]
          .replace("requiredType", "required_type")
          .concat(`.${data.split(".")[1]}`);
        Topic.push(requiredType);
      }
    }
    if (data.split(".")[0].includes("Entry")) {
      if (rest.includes(data.split(".")[1])) {
        entries = data
          .split(".")[0]
          .replace("Entry", "entries")
          .concat(`.${data.split(".")[1]}.demo`);
        Topic.push(entries);
      } else {
        entries = data
          .split(".")[0]
          .replace("Entry", "entries")
          .concat(`.${data.split(".")[1]}.demo`);
        Topic.push(entries);
      }
    }
    if (data.split(".")[0].includes("token")) {
      if (rest.includes(data.split(".")[1])) {
        token = data
          .split(".")[0]
          .replace("token", "tokens")
          .concat(`.${data.split(".")[1]}`);
        Topic.push(token);
      } else {
        token = data
          .split(".")[0]
          .replace("token", "tokens")
          .concat(`.${data.split(".")[1]}`);
        Topic.push(token);
      }
    }
    if (
      data.split(".")[0].includes("RestAPI") &&
      !data.split(".")[0].includes("RestAPIAction")
    ) {
      restAPI = data
        .split(".")[0]
        .replace("RestAPI", "restAPI")
        .concat(`.deploy`);
      Topic.push(restAPI);
    }
  }
});

console.log(Topic);
```

Is there any possible way I can reduce the code without effecting the output

As the requirement of the code is like if the topicValue contain * or the other value so I wrote this long code and now I am trying to minimize the code so its look short and effective.

Comment: if the code works codereview SE might be a better place to ask

Comment: Are you sure though that you want to use `include`? Is `'stoken'.includes('token')` what you want?

Comment: Hi @trincot I am trying to minimize the code as the code is working fine but at some part I thing I have wrote same code twice

Comment: That is not an answer to my comment?

Comment: So you expect us to dig into your code and try to find out what the logic is? I think what you need to do is tell is exactly what you want the logic to be. The code has lots of inconsistencies: some blocks have similar code, but then not exactly. Some do more than others, and there seems no logic to it.

Comment: you have three types, and a replacement scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made refactoring only if(true) part of your code. You can implement the else part by yourself. I didn't run the code, spend any time for proper naming, etc. So it was quick refactoring to give you an idea. I think there is a mistake in else block because both if and else parts of tokens and Entry are doing the same thing.

```js
let replace = {
  requiredType: 'required_type',
  Entry: 'entries',
  token: 'tokens',
  RestAPI: 'restAPI'
}

const run = () => {
  topicsValue.map((data) => task(data));
}

const task = (data) => {
  data.split(".")[1].includes("*") ? funcIf(data) : funcElse(data);
}

const funcIf = (data) => {
  for (const key in replace) {
      if (data.split(".")[0].includes(key)) commonTask(key, data);
  }
}

const commonTask = (key, data) => {
  if (key == 'RestAPI' && data.split(".")[0].includes("RestAPIAction")) return;

  final.forEach(value => Topic.push(makeOutput(key, value, data)));
}

const makeOutput = (key, value, data) => {
  return data.split(".")[0]
    .replace(key, replace[key])
    .concat(key == 'restAPI' ? '.deploy' : `.${value}`);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bulent I have edited else entry part to add more clarification :) thank you for your code this help me alot what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

Try using the && operator.

```
if(y==1 && x == 1) {
do somthing
}
```

it only runs if both statements are true.